# Xamarin: Back button in Detail of MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, uwp, back-button, master-detail

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114 to build a cross platform app. I'm starting with the UWP app, right now debugging as a desktop application.

This is the current navigation path:

Main menu (ContentPage) -> Contents (MasterDetailPage)

MasterDetailPage:

-> Master (ContentPage) contains a list of items showing via ListView

-> Detail (ContentPage) displays data from a single list item

The Xamarin documentation says:

> The detail page is presented to the user by setting the MasterDetailPage.IsPresented property to false.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

So I made the ListView in the master page public, and added code similiar to the following to the MasterDetailPage:

```
public MyMasterDetailPage()
{
    this.Master.ItemsListView.ItemSelected += MasterListView_ItemSelected;
}

private void MasterListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Master.ItemsListView.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Detail.BindingContext = this.Master.ItemsListView.SelectedItem;

    this.IsPresented = false;
}
```

The detail page shows the details of the selected item, so this is working fine.

However, there is a back button showing. When being on the Detail page, the back button brings me back to the Main menu content page, as opposed to the Master page, which would be the expected behavior in my eyes. What is the intended way to achieve this behavior?

Here is what I've tried:

Of course this behavior is because the Detail page has not been pushed into the navigation stack. Pushing the Detail page instance in there in the ItemSelected event causes an exeption, because its Parent property is already set.

I've tried wrapping the Detail page in a Navigation page when setting the Detail property of the MasterDetailPage, but this prevents the back button from showing, which is apparently caused by the NavigationPage claiming the  Navigation stack or something along those lines. I've also tried making the Detail page inherit from NavigationPage as opposed to ContentPage, with the same result.

I'm not sure whether I'm looking for the right thing here, seems to me like I have some misunderstanding in the way MasterDetailPages are supposed to be used. Any help is appreciated.

This is the project which shows this behavior.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!At78FKXjEGEohocQQgxaZuCYT2rwMw

Start the UWP app, click on "List", click on any item on the left. Click the back button and you should see my problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you said the current code makes the Back Button visible, how did you do that? Any demo will be helpful to understand your question. The detail page should only be populated with TabbedPage, NavigationPage, and ContentPage instances, if you are choosing MasterDetailPage, the NavigationPage is used to fit your scenario

Comment: Hi Franklin, I added a link to the problematic project at the end of the post. I did not do anything special to make the back button show up, it must be automatic due to there being a navigation stack.

Comment: Its weird because I get no back button. So once I get to the master/detail page I'm stuck there

Answer (score 0):

> When being on the Detail page, the back button brings me back to the Main menu content page, as opposed to the Master page, which would be the expected behavior in my eyes. What is the intended way to achieve this behavior?

Yes, your assumption is correct, this is due to the specific page was missing in navigation back stack.

The default behavior of Xamarin Master Detail page can't implement your full requirement.

The right way in this scenario is to use [`Navigation.PushAsync`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/). This method asynchronously adds a Page to the top of the navigation stack.

> Pushing the Detail page instance in there in the ItemSelected event causes an exeption, because its Parent property is already set.

Looks like you have assinged the Detail property of MasterDetailPage in xaml

```
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <pages:LeadDetailPage />
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Please directly add a `ContentPage` to stack, this will make your navigation correctly.

Use the following code in the **`LeadsMainPage.xmal.cs`** file:

```
private void LeadsList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
            if (_masterPage.LeadsList.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            ContentPage detailpage = new LeadDetailPage();
            detailpage.BindingContext= _masterPage.LeadsList.SelectedItem;
            Navigation.PushAsync(detailpage);

            this.IsPresented = false;
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this certainly works. A few things though: with this approach I don't see any reason to use MasterDetailPage at all. Also, behaviors like swiping left or right to switch between Master and Detail won't work anymore once I get to other platforms (which is default on iOS I think?). I was under the assumption that the MasterDetailPage brings all those master detail behaviors under the same page, but it feels like this isn't its purpose at all. So what exactly is the right scenario to use MasterDetailPage, if not my current one?

Comment: In my experience, the behavior of MasterDetailPage is a little like the [Hamburger Menu in UWP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quick_thoughts/2015/06/01/windows-10-splitview-build-your-first-hamburger-menu/), but by using SplitView control, the Hamburger Menu supports navi back button on the top left title bar. In Xamarin, it has not add supported for this scenario. The common way in UWP, Template10 is the recommend template: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki